# How to update ListView in Android after an IntentService returns something to an ResultReceiver

Tags: android, database, listview, intentservice

Perhaps the reason I can't find an answer to this, is that I'm doing the question the wrong way, but still I hope that here on SO someone can answer this.

I have a MainActivity with a ListView that present some values - after processing - from a database:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView mainViewList;
    CTTObjectsArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<CTTObject> cttObjects = null;
    public UpdateObjectResultReceiver updateObjectReceiver;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Update all the Objects in the DB
        CTTUtilities.updateAllObjects(context, updateObjectReceiver);
        // DB stuff
        CTTObjectsDataSource dataSource = new CTTObjectsDataSource(context);
        dataSource.open();

        // Initialize ListView
        mainViewList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMain);

        // Initialize our ArrayList
        cttObjects = new ArrayList<CTTObject>();
        cttObjects = dataSource.getAllObjects();
        dataSource.close();

        // Initialize our array adapter notice how it references the
        // listMain.xml layout
        arrayAdapter = new CTTObjectsArrayAdapter(context,
                R.layout.main_list_row_layout, cttObjects);

        // Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
        mainViewList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Now, what I need, is to call the following snippet that updates the ListView when the updateObjectReceiver variable receives an answer from the Intent Service that I started and that updated the database:

```
cttObjects.clear();
CTTObjectsDataSource dataSource = new CTTObjectsDataSource(context);
dataSource.open();
cttObjects.addAll(dataSource.getAllObjects());
dataSource.close();
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

How can I do this then?

**EDIT:**

After implementing the receiver.send and the method proposed below, the app fails with:

```
07-23 20:30:40.435: W/dalvikvm(3467): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c88930)
07-23 20:30:40.435: E/AndroidRuntime(3467): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[UpdateObjectIntentService]
07-23 20:30:40.435: E/AndroidRuntime(3467): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 20:30:40.435: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at info.hecatosoft.ctttrack2.UpdateObjectIntentService.onHandleIntent(UpdateObjectIntentService.java:89)
07-23 20:30:40.435: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
07-23 20:30:40.435: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 20:30:40.435: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 20:30:40.435: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

**EDIT 2:**

It fails in the line: `receiver.send(STATUS_UPDATED_CHANGED, Bundle.EMPTY);`

The code in question is:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // ---process the received extras to the service call and get the URL
        // from it---
        this.receiver = arg0.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER_KEY);
        String recTrackNo = arg0.getStringExtra("trackNo");
        Log.i("jbssmDeveloper", "received trackNo=" + recTrackNo);

        String jsonDataString = null;

            jsonDataString = getHTTPJSONData(recTrackNo);

            if (jsonDataString != null) {
                dataSource = new CTTObjectsDataSource(getBaseContext());
                dataSource.open();
                CTTObject cttObject = dataSource
                        .getObjectWithTrackNo(recTrackNo);
                dataSource.close();
                updateDB(cttObject, jsonDataString);
                receiver.send(STATUS_UPDATED_CHANGED, Bundle.EMPTY);
            }
            receiver.send(STATUS_ERROR, Bundle.EMPTY);
        this.stopSelf();
    }
```

Comment: NPE. Will need to see the code when this exception occurs.

Comment: Make sure you have `intent.putExtra(RECEIVER_KEY, updateObjectReceiver)` before starting the service.

Comment: Another problem(unrelated to NPE) I see: You have `receiver.send(STATUS_UPDATED_CHANGED, Bundle.EMPTY);` inside the if block, which you call only when `jsonDataString` is not `null`. But, `receiver.send(STATUS_ERROR, Bundle.EMPTY);` is always called (irrespective of whether `jsonDataString` is null or not). Is this by choice?

Comment: I do have the `intent.putExtra(RECEIVER_KEY, updateObjectReceiver)`. About the unrelated problem you mentioned. No that was not on purpose, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I wasn't setting the setReceiver method because it didn't work in the MainActivity. I'll see a workaround.

Comment: Hope your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `onReceiveResult(int, Bundle)` of `UpdateObjectResultReceiver`:

```
@Override
protected void onReceiveResult (int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

    cttObjects.clear();
    CTTObjectsDataSource dataSource = new CTTObjectsDataSource(context);
    dataSource.open();
    cttObjects.addAll(dataSource.getAllObjects());
    dataSource.close();
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

You will have to pass your activity's context when you initialize the ResultReceiver.

**Edit**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

....
....
....

    public void showResults() {
        cttObjects.clear();
        CTTObjectsDataSource dataSource = new CTTObjectsDataSource(MainActivity.this);
        dataSource.open();
        cttObjects.addAll(dataSource.getAllObjects());
        dataSource.close();
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

....
....
....



    class UpdateObjectResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    ....
    ....
    ....

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult (int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            MainActivity.this.showResults();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems the way to go, but I need to pass my cttObjects and arrayAdapter as well, right? And how do I pass that and the context? In the constructor?

Comment: You can have `UpdateObjectResultReceiver` as an inner class to `MainActivity`. Put the refresh code in a method of `MainActivity` and call it from `onReceiveResult(int, Bundle)`. See my edit above.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer your question: `And how do I pass that and the context? In the constructor?`. Yes, you can do that. Or, have a setter method inside `UpdateObjectResultReceiver` to set the context variable after you initialize an `UpdateObjectResultReceiver` object. --> `public void setContext(Mainactivity context) { mContext = context; }`. But, with the edit above, you won't need to do this.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm trying to implement this, but my app is crashing when I call the receiver.send from the IntentService this way. I'm trying to see what is wrong.

Comment: @jbssm What exception do you get? Can you post the `logcat` output?

Comment: Sure, I just put it in the main question since I couldn't put it here. But I think the problem is not from your answer, it's from the ResultReceiver.send method and what I'm putting in it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating and UpdateObjectResultReceiver, make it an interface and then implement it in your activity. Then add the callback method to your activity and run the code within it.